# Converting TIFF to JPEG using .NET

Tags: .net, jpeg, tiff, libtiff.net

I need to convert a TIFF to JPEG using .NET.

I have already done this succesfully using Windows 7 with a simple `Bitmap.Save()`. But it seems that this doesn't work on Windows XP (Windows 7 has more complete support for TIFF images).

I saw that there is a .NET library called LibTiff.Net that works well with TIFF, but I didn't find any example code.

Any ideas? Any sample code to convert JPEG to TIFF?

Really thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to convert TIFF to JPEG (as stated in title of the question) and not JPEG to TIFF (as stated in the question body)

Here is a sample that creates [System.Drawing.Bitmap from a TIFF](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo24BitBitmap).

You can save the bitmap as a JPEG file.

Comment: If we have a very large image, we get OverflowException on initialization of the raster array. Any other way to do this where we handle the image in chunks or stream it instead of loading it all into memory?