# Converting 8-bit grayscale tiff image to 8-bit grayscale jpg in .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, image-processing, .net-2.0

We have a system that provides images in 8-bit grayscale either tiff or jpg formats. However, the component we have to process the images expects image to be in 8-bit jpg format.

When I use .Net to save the tiff images as jpg it convets it to 24-bit image.

Is there a way, hopefully simple and fast, to convert 8-bit grayscale tiff images to equivalent jpg?

Comment: Do you have some example jpg files the target component will accept? I suspect they are also 24 bit images (the norm for jpg) but each of the red, green and blue channels will hold the same data.

Comment: Very obscure, GDI+ doesn't support it.  Try the JpegBitmapEncoder class with a BitmapPalettes.Gray256 palette.

Comment: @ChrisF, I'm not a jpg expert but this is what Windows and IrfanView are telling me. For example, if I view the properties of the jpg file I see the Bit depth is 8. I'll see if I can upload a sample picture somewhere.

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't know if your suggested solution works, but unfortunately I use .Net 2.0 which does not support `BitmapPalettes.Gray256 `.

Comment: I'll never understand why a programmer gets stuck on a 8 year old piece of code when the update is free and takes 10 minutes to install.  Time to get these questions closed as "too localized".

Comment: @HansPassant, we can all have a fantasy where everybody is up-to-date and "old" technologies don't need to be supported or we can look at real life and see how different it is. So, "why a programmer gets stuck on a 8 year old piece of code"? Because your client said so; you can't just upgrade a working system just for the sake of upgrading it. Is it "too localized"? I don't think so. .Net 2.0 is widely used and still totally supported framework. If you're waiting it to die take my advice and don't hold your breath; I guess you'll wait not less than 2 years from today.

Comment: The 2.0 installer was removed from Microsoft's download service 3 months ago.

Comment: What is the problem here? You're not saying that the component only supports 8-bit JPEG files, you're saying it only supports JPEG files. Just give it the 24-bit JPEG?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I'm talking about 8-bit images so 8-bit jpg was implied :) anyway, I modified the questions.

Comment: some conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430575/converting-tiff-to-jpeg-using-net Have you checked?

Answer (score 2):

I tried and tried just to conclude that I'm sorry: .Net library's Bitmap class DOES NOT save JPEG as 8bpp even when explicitly stated and data is in grayscale.

(note: although stated in some places, JPEG format DOES support 8bpp).

At [Convert an image to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265910/c-convert-image-to-grayscale) you may find code snipet to convert to grayscale any Image.

Using that code, I was able to save a 8bpp grayscale Image instance with '.jpeg' extension, but stating ImageFormat.Gif... that's a cheat...

My findings show as solution an entirely different approach.

The FreeImage library offers powerful APIs, including the feature needed to solve your problem.

It's home page is at http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/faq.html

But, I could not easily compile it in my Win2008 + VS 2010 machine.

One ought to sweat a lot to make it run on modern environments.

Some hints on how to accomplish that are found at http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/05/freeimage-and-x64-projects-yes-you-can/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(filePathOriginal);
Bitmap bmp = ConvertTo8bpp(img);
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8);
bmp.Save(filePathNew, jpgCodec, parameters);
bmp.Dispose();
img.Dispose();
```

...

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo8bpp(Image img) {
    var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
     gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
}

return bmp;
}
```

Comment: ColorDepth is not obeyed by Image.Save for ImageFormat.Jpeg... although elegant and straightforward, this code does not works.